# Why can't I see my Canvas output?

Tags: javafx-8

I have been trying to use JavaFX to draw a Ferris Wheel for a class project. Every time I run the program, it does not show the wheel(the rest of the project is not finished yet). I've looked on a few other similar questions,but they were not showing up for bits of code not included in my program. What's wrong with it? If anyone can help, that would be great!
[image: Ferris_Wheel]

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! You can [edit] your question to include the needed informations.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. You have created a JavaFX application, but never called `show()` on the mainStage. You have created a `GraphicsContext` from the canvas but never drawn anything on it. I am not sure if this is all you have written, but I would still go ahead and advice you to start reading [Getting Started with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm) and [Working with Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm)

Comment: Instead of posting a screen shot of your code, can you [edit] the question and paste the code directly in there? This will allow you to include code that doesn't fit in your image, and will also allow others to easily copy and paste it. (Once you have pasted the code, select it, then press the "code" button ("{ }") at the top of the editor to format it correctly.)